# Sublime Error trying to parse settings: Expected value in Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings:1:1

Tags: sublimetext3

So, suddenly my Sublime crashed, and now when I boot it up I get the following:

Error trying to parse settings: Expected value in Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings:1:1

I'm using v3.0 build 3143.  Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Select `Preferences > Settings - User` from the menu; there's something broken in the first character of your user preferences. The :1:1 means "Line 1, Column 1".

Comment: Oh, perfect!  Yeah, for some reason a "/" got in before the "{".  Not sure how that happened, but solved.  Thank you much!

Answer (score 5):

Solved the issue by searching C:// Users -> Packages->PHP.sublime-settings and completely deleted that file.And found the crashing issue got solved...

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before answering any question. Thanks.